# Retrieve values from a dynamic table, in a form, inside Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm developing a website. Inside it, there is a web flow, where there is a table, which is filled by the user, but I don't know the number of rows that table will have, because there is an "add row" button, so the user enters the values he/she wants. How could I get those values entered by the user to persist them in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your flowscope form as YourForm and each row in the table is represented by a POJO let's say User, create a row list in yourForm as:

```
    public class YourForm implements Serializable{
        private List<User> rowList = new ArrayList<User>();
        //other form fields and setters and getters for all these fields
    }
```

and User class is:

```
    public class User{
        // row fields to be displayed/captured from user in table 
    }
```

In your view jsp:

```
    //create a javascript function as:      
    function addRow(eventID){
        document.getElementById("yourForm")._eventId.value = eventID;   
        document.getElementById("yourForm").submit(); 
    }
```

and then

```
    //When user clicks on add row, a new row with empty form fields will be displayed along with existing ones as:
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('addRow');"/>
    <c:forEach items="${yourForm.rowList}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
        //Display rows with corresponding fields
    </c:forEach>
```

In your flow:

```
    <view-state id="someView" view="someView">      
    <transition on="addRow">
         <evaluate expression="yourAction.addRow(flowScope.yourForm)"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="addToDatabase" to="addToDatabase">
    </view-state>
```

Note: if transition 'to' is not specified then same view will be displayed after evaluate.
In your action class the addRow method is:

```
    public void addRow(YourForm yourForm) throws Exception{
        yourForm.getRowList().add(new User());
    }
```

When user finally wants to persist all rows by clicking on a button which generates the event 'addToDatabase', convert all user entered form list(rowList) into entities and persist. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: I finally could test this, Prasad, and with this approach it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: What does addToDatabase does? I have a same scenario could not find any workaround any help would be appreciated! @Prasad

Comment: Are u still on board? @Frustigador